# Java efficiently comparing bits of equally sizes byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, performance, bit-manipulation

How would one **efficiently** compare two bits of equally sized `byte[]` In Java? `BitSet` might be used by constructing them from given arrays, however this approach is not as for example efficient as shifting through the arrays using bit manipulation and bitmasks. What would be implementation be alike?

Comment: You can look at post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575142/comparing-arbitrary-bit-sequences-in-a-byte-array-in-c

Comment: @Akash The question assumes that one is dealing with bite arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> `BitSet` might be used by constructing them from given arrays, however this approach is not as for example efficient as shifting through the arrays using bit manipulation and bitmasks.

`BitSet` actually uses bit manipulation and bit masks under the hood.
If you still want to use only `byte[]` (e.g. to avoid overhead on `BitSet` construction from `byte[]`), take a look at [BitSet#get(int) implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/BitSet.java#621)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a long value by reading 64 bit chunk from first array;
- Create another long value by reading 64 bit chunk from second array;
- If XOR of both longs is not 0, these chunks had some value that was different;
- If you are done with entire length of array and all XORs were 0, the arrays were same.